# C# test project Wipe database before the tests are run

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, unit-testing

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 application, where i need to test a database wrapper class. This is up and running. But i need to recreate the database, when the test starts. I need to wipe all data in database. The database is a test double.

I have the SQL script creating the database. For now im running this manualy in "SQL Server Manager" and it works. But I would like to have the script run before a new test run.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Replacing with a decent answer.

Create a C# class that looks like this -

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  [SetUpFixture]
  public class MySetUpClass
  {
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
      // Set up my database with SQL scripts run via SqlCommand
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void RunAfterAnyTests()
    {
      // tear down my database  with SQL scripts run via SqlCommand
    }
  }
}
```

That should run setup once only before any tests, and then teardown once only after all tests have completed.

I realize I'm raising this one from the dead but I felt it was time it got a decent answer.

In any case, there is a much better way.  Mock your datalayer and test that.  Then make certain everything done with SQL Server is in the form of Stored Procedures and Functions.  Then use Visual Studio to create unit tests for those sprocs and functions.

If you have logic in your repositories, I recommend grabbing [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) and making use of its AutoInterface feature.  That way, your repository layer is merely an interface, which you can easily mock and move on.

Comment: I already have this scripts. I drops all tables, then recrates them. But I can't figure out, how to to run this script before my test run.

The database im testing aginst is deployed on my local SQLExpress server.

Comment: Well, I guess you could do it from code and use the content of your script as the SqlCommand.Text property.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code within your unit test class.  You should do all your database creation here. The TestInitialize runs before any tests begin.  This will happen once, ever time a unit test is started.

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        -
    }
```

Comment: But im not looking for a action to run before each test.
I just need to recreate the DB, with a .sql file, when ever i start the test run.